# como añadir los dias festivos de google a fullcalendar

Tags: php, fullcalendar, google-calendar

buen dia, siguiendo el ejemplo demo de la libreria fullcalendar , puedo mostrar de forma correcta , los dias festivos de la localidad que seleccione.
pero , estoy usando adicionalmente php para poder mostrar datos ingresados en una base de datos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='../gcal.min.js'></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,listYear'
      },

      displayEventTime: false, // don't show the time column in list view

      // THIS KEY WON'T WORK IN PRODUCTION!!!
      // To make your own Google API key, follow the directions here:
      // http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/
      googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDcnW6WejpTOCffshGDDb4neIrXVUA1EAE',

      // US Holidays
      events: 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',

      eventClick: function(event) {
        // opens events in a popup window
        window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
        return false;
      },

      loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
      }

    });

  });

</script>
<style>

  body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #loading {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id='loading'>loading...</div>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

este es el demo del calendar para ejecutarlo en la pc . ahora 
yo me traigo los datos del evento de la siguiente manera

```
events: [
<?php foreach($events as $event): 
                $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $start = $start[0];
                }else{
                    $start = $event['start'];
                }
                if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $end = $end[0];
                }else{
                    $end = $event['end'];
                }
            ?>
                {
                    id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                    title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                    start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                    end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                    color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
                    lugar: '<?php echo $event['lugar']; ?>',
                    motivo: '<?php echo $event['motivo']; ?>',
                    fuente: '<?php echo $event['fuente']; ?>',
                    tipo: '<?php echo $event['tipo']; ?>',
                    hora: '<?php echo $event['hora']; ?>',
                    fotografo: '<?php echo $event['fotografo']; ?>',
                    descripcion: '<?php echo $event['descripcion']; ?>',
                    reportero: '<?php echo $event['reportero']; ?>',
                    etiquetas: '<?php echo $event['etiquetas']; ?>',
                    razonmodificacion: '<?php echo $event['razonmodificacion']; ?>',

                },
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]
        });
```

mi duda principalmente es como agregar los resultados de google a los buscados en mi base de datos para luego mostrarlos en el array